# Pytest for package for data processing

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I am trying to include pytests for the project I am working on. I struggle with two parts of it.

1. Some algorithms are quite complex, including FFT etc. So the easy examples like `assert add(1, 1) == 2` does not apply here, because the function is needed to calculate the expected output. In what way can we tackle it so that the assert is independent of the function it tests?
2. Data processing is also involved, processing of 1 file can take up to 20 minutes. Is it necessary to include tests for the reading of a file? Or is it sufficient to create a small file and use that for the tests? The reason I doubt this, is because the file will never be a "edge case". I understood that edge cases are the ones that we want test the most.

For the first problem one can think of a simple function which in my opinion is hard to test:

```py
import numpy as np
from typing import Union

def get_grid(x: Union[list, np.ndarray], y: Union[list, np.ndarray]):
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    return np.sin(X) + np.cos(Y)
```

So one way to test this is to call the function, save the output as plain text and assert this output with the function call:

```
def test_get_grid():
    assert np.allclose(
        get_grid([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]), 
        np.array([
           [ 1.38177329,  1.44959973,  0.68142231],
           [ 0.42532415,  0.49315059, -0.27502683],
           [-0.14852151, -0.08069507, -0.84887249]])
    )
```

But this test the function with its own output. This may be useful when the code changes and to check if the output with previous version is the same, but this is not a real test in my opinion since it does net test the expected outcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tests are there to meet multiple outcomes.

1. You want to assure yourself that your code is doing what it's supposed to do as part of development. This is the first reason most coders think of, but ironically enough, this is probably the weakest reason of all. In building your code, you're likely to run portions of it, make diagnostics/adjustments until it appears to be doing what you want. It can be useful to promote some of these (often ad-hoc) development tests to being catered for within your test suite, and doing so helps document what it is you want the code to do.
2. You want to assure others that your code is doing what it's supposed to do. From a managerial point of view, code that can demonstrate that it still meets its test-cases will make people feel safer using it. Having a range of well commented tests can help new team members figure out the in-house style and demonstrate some of the patterns employed by the team in setting out the code. Often there will be choices where different coders might employ different styles, having a set of tests demoing how things work can help get everyone on the same page.
3. You want to ensure that your code *continues* to do the things its supposed to do after you, or your team add new features or otherwise change the code, or other dependencies on which the code relies.
4. You want to demonstrate and document your code, showing people (or yourself) how it works, how to get it to run under different scenarios, and to maintain commentary on progress.

Determining which tests you think will best meet all of these aims is an active problem, you have to spend time thinking about how to construct a given test will meet one or all of these criteria.

A good rule of thumb is to aim to have some test coverage across every line of code in your test suite. If you try to achieve this, then you'll have a metric that you can use to work towards (100% coverage) though it's also a good idea to prioritise your test suite to cover the parts of the code that are most vulnerable to change, or that you think needs special attention.

If you're confident that loading a file is iron-clad, then fine, but edge cases may exist where the filename is incorrectly spelled, where the underlying file is missing or corrupt, or where there's something else that's a problem. Tests might be built to ensure that your code handles each of these issues "gracefully" where you get to define what "graceful" means. Some of these types of test might work equally well with a "dummy" file, than with the full-sized production version - it depends on the meaning you ascribe to the test. If it's just to assert that file handling in general is covered, then great. It's likely that you will have a spread of things that you want to have under your test coverage, some of which might only be testable with more lifelike data and volume.

If you have a complex algorithm that returns values in some bounded range, you might explicitly test that the answers that algorithm returns are indeed within that range. Over time, you can try to identify tighter ranges that are more meaningful, using better and more accurate estimation functions. Not only does this capture situations where perhaps the wrong algorithm gets assigned, but might also help develop useful opportunities in making fast estimates that might help other processes along without all the processing time required to run the definitive algo. If your algo generates an 3x3 matrix given an input of 3x3, then you can test that the format remains within expectations for a range of input formats.

If you're the only person who's ever going to look at the code, then your test scripts can act as a "diary" describing and documenting your thinking at the time you built the thing. Comments should also be in the codebase itself, but sometimes as you're developing, you might not be as clear or sure of certain things. Putting this kind of commentary into your test suite can act as a useful place to record this kind of development history that might be of use if you return to the code maybe 6 or 18 months later, and have forgotten what it was you were thinking when you first built it.

So, there are many reasons for writing tests, you can segregate your test scripts to support each of these reasons, or pile them all together. It's entirely up to you. Having a single set of tests that can all run to completion and success will help you in the future when you or someone else makes changes to your code-base and you want to identify what the impact is of any of those changes. For larger code-bases with many thousands of lines of code, and multiple developers all working on different functionality simultaneously, this becomes an absolute necessity.